# how to inject persistencejs in angularjs (undefined is not an object (evaluating 'persistence.store.cordovasql.config'))

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite

Hello I want to use [persistencejs](https://github.com/coresmart/persistencejs) in my angularjs/ionic mobile application. I use a sqlite database on the device.

I used this [example](https://github.com/coresmart/persistencejs/blob/master/demo/jquerymobile/index.html) to use persistencejs in my application but I get an error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'persistence.store.cordovasql.config')
```

In my index.html I bind the js files like this:

```
  <script src="lib/persistencejs/persistence.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/persistencejs/persistence.store.sql.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/persistencejs/persistence.store.sqlite.js"></script>
```

And in my controller I use:

```
  persistence.store.cordovasql.config(
  persistence,
  'testdb',
  '0.0.1',                // DB version
  'DB',                   // DB display name
  5 * 1024 * 1024,        // DB size
  0                       // SQLitePlugin Background processing disabled
  );

  persistence.define('Page', {
    path: "TEXT",
    data: "TEXT"
  });

  persistence.schemaSync();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you include the cordovasql script?

```
<script src="lib/persistencejs/persistence.store.cordovasql.js"></script>
```

PS. For some reason installing persistencejs with bower didnt work for me. I manually downloaded the github repo from https://github.com/coresmart/persistencejs